# Get IP address of Docker with Ansible

Tags: docker, ansible

I have follow playbook command:

```
  - name: Docker | Consul | Get ip
    shell: "docker inspect --format {% raw %}'{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' {% endraw %} consul"
    register: consul_ip
```

After run ansible return follow error:

> fatal: [192.168.122.41]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "{u'cmd':
>   u\"docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' 
>   consul\", u'end': u'2017-01-18 16:52:18.786469',
>   u'stdout': u'172.17.0.2', u'changed': True, u'start': u'2017-01-18
>   16:52:18.773819', u'delta': u'0:00:00.012650', u'stderr': u'', u'rc':
>   0, 'stdout_lines': [u'172.17.0.2'], u'warnings': []}: template error
>   while templating string: unexpected '.'. String: docker inspect
>   --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' consul"}

Ansible version:

```
ansible 2.2.1.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
```

How right way to get IP address of container?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Trick with bash concatenation ability:

```
shell: "docker inspect --format '{''{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }''}' consul"
```

This will stick together `{`+`{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }`+`}` into single string in bash.

Update: the root cause of this behaviour is [described here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/20400).

Comment: Thanks, I also put a sample of exporting Names and Status. `shell: docker ps -a --format='{''{.Names}''}{''{.Status}''}'`

Answer (score 7):

Another way is using [docker_container_info](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_container_info_module.html)

```
- name: Get infos on container
  docker_container_info:
    name:{{ container_name }}
  register: result

- name: Does container exist?
  debug:
    msg: "The container {{ 'exists' if result.exists else 'does not exist' }}"

- name: Print information about container
  debug:
    var: result.container.NetworkSettings.IPAddress
  when: result.exists
```

Output will be like below.

[image]

Comment: Actually I prefer this solution because it uses a module. Maybe you need to adapt accessing the actual variable depending on your network settings but just have a look at the output of your docker logs or `result.container` to find the needed value.

Comment: Hi, using ansible-playbook 2.9.22 it doesn't work for me, it returns an empty string. Dumping result.container.NetworkSettings  I've seen it returns a complex object with lots of fields, I tried result.container.NetworkSettings.Networks.my_network_name.IPAddress but it doesn't work. Any help will be very appreciated.