# Using {{ and }} in ansible shell command

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have this in my playbook:

```
- name: Get facts about containers
  shell: "docker ps -f name=jenkins --format {%raw%}{{.Names}}{% endraw %}"
  register: container
```

Note, that I inserted the `{%raw%}` and `{%endraw%}` so that ansible does not evaulate the '{{'.

If I run this, I get this error:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "{u'cmd': u'docker ps -f name=jenkins --format {{.Names}}', u'end': u'2017-01-19 10:04:27.491648', u'stdout': u'ecs-sde-abn-17-jenkins-ec8eccee8c9eb8e38f01', u'changed': True, u'start': u'2017-01-19 10:04:27.481090', u'delta': u'0:00:00.010558', u'stderr': u'', u'rc': 0, 'stdout_lines': [u'ecs-task-17-jenkins-ec8eccee8c9eb8e38f01'], u'warnings': []}: template error while templating string: unexpected '.'. String: docker ps -f name=jenkins --format {{.Names}}"}

In other words, the command ran succesfully (the output ecs-task-17-jenkins-ec8eccee8c9eb8e38f01 is correct), but than it tries the template the string ... again?

What is going wrong here and how can I fix this?

**EDITED**

Escaping the `{{` like this:

```
shell: "docker ps -f name=jenkins --format {{ '{' }}{.Names}{{ '}' }}"
```

results in the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get IP address of docker with ansible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41721353/get-ip-address-of-docker-with-ansible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem introduced in Ansible 2.2.1: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/20400.
Happens when registering variable with `{{` inside.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41721634/2795592) workaround prevent `{{` from appearing in registered variable:

```
shell: "docker inspect --format '{''{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }''}' consul"
```

Way to reproduce the bug:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - shell: "echo '{''{.Names}''}'"
      register: myvar    
    - debug: var=myvar
```

Comment: @techraf added code example to the answer. Until you touch `myvar` everything works (comment out `debug`), when you try to use `myvar`, it fails.

Comment: @techraf yes, because it echoes `{{.Names}}` which pops up in `stdout` key of result (redirect echo to file and everything will be good). For OP task my workaround works, because there is no output with double braces and `cmd` key has this trick to prevent double braces in registered variable.